# turning OFF simple text-writing code slows down app

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I'm programming a simple game in SFML/C++/Code::blocks. I wrote a simple "dev-console" which basically prints out in the corner fps, position, number of logic/ graphics loops etc. 
Everything works fine until I hide it, then fps fall down from 60(blocked max) to around 15. Why disabling writing function causes so much fps drop? (shouldn't disabling it speed things up a little?)

Declarations:

```
sf::Text consoletxt;
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("Times_New_Roman.ttf"))
    std::cout<<"Error loading font Times New Roman"<<std::endl;
consoletxt.setFont(font);
consoletxt.setFillColor(sf::Color(255,255,255,255));
consoletxt.setCharacterSize(14);
consoletxt.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(0,0,0,192));
consoletxt.setOutlineThickness(1);
bool console = true;
```

Code below: upon switching console = false; fps drops from 60 to 15

```
tm = t.asMilliseconds();
    fps += 1000/tm;
    if (console == true)
    {
        consoletxt.setString("Last loop time: " + doubleToString(tm));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,0);
        window.draw(consoletxt);
        consoletxt.setString("Fps: " + intToString(1000/tm) + " Average fps: " + intToString(fps/logicLoops));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,15);
        window.draw(consoletxt);
        consoletxt.setString("objects[0].x: " + doubleToString(objects[0].x));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,30);
        window.draw(consoletxt);
        consoletxt.setString("objects[0].y: " + doubleToString(objects[0].y));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,45);
        window.draw(consoletxt);
        consoletxt.setString("Angle radians/degrees: " + doubleToString(cam_angle) + " | " + intToString((int)(cam_angle*180/pi)));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,60);
        window.draw(consoletxt);
        consoletxt.setString("Logical Loops: " + doubleToString(logicLoops) + " Graphics loops: " + doubleToString(graphicsLoops) + " Difference: " + doubleToString(logicLoops - graphicsLoops - 1));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,75);
        window.draw(consoletxt);
        consoletxt.setString("Variable test: " + doubleToString(cos(cam_angle*180/3.1415)));
        consoletxt.setPosition(0,585);
        //window.draw(consoletxt);
    }
```

Comment: we need an [mcve], what is `t`? how are you calculating fps, is it definitely correct? What is the remaining code that is running slowly?

Comment: variable tm is a time which passed during rendering of previous frame, fps is calculated simply by dividing 1000 by the times of previous frame in miliseconds. 
I've commented out the rest of the code and still, hiding this causes fps drop